# How do I repeat select elements in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a select/drop down in my HTML page which has to appear about 10 times in the page. Simple sample for that would be as below:

> Qn 1: {dropdown} is a {TextField}
>
> Qn 2: {dropdown} is a {TextField}
>
> Qn 3: {dropdown} is a {TextField}

Where dropdown lists various options which are same and static (array of strings - no server component).

I want to create the dropdown once and use it. Can CSS have data elements for the html:select?  Or how do I write javascript code to fill the select elements?

Comment: [what have you tried ?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Mayank - I have just added multiple selects with individual data in each select.

Comment: please show some code so we can help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way (using jQuery to make selecting and iterating through all dropdowns easier):

```
<p>Qn 1: <select class="repeat"></select> is a {TextField}</p>
<p>Qn 2: <select class="repeat"></select> is a {TextField}</p>
<p>Qn 3: <select class="repeat"></select> is a {TextField}​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​</p>​​​​​​​​​

<script type="text/javascript">
    var optionOpen = "<option>";
    var optionClosed = "</option>"​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​;​​
    var selectItems = ["firstItem", "secondItem", "thirdItem"];

    $(".repeat").each(function(){
        for (key in selectItems)
        {
            $(this).append(optionOpen + selectItems[key] + optionClosed);
        }
    });
</script>
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Snowsickle/bf67h/)

I formatted the select options as a list and concatenated the strings to make it easy to change and reuse between pages.  Simply add options to the `selectItems` list to add them to each `<select>` tag with the class `repeat`.  Give each `<select>` a different `name` attribute if you need the form to process them separately.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here's the first one that came to mind:

Provide a "template" row for the first line:

```
<ul>
    <li class="template">Qn <span class="qnum">1</span>:
        <select name="sel">
            <option val="0"></option>
            <option val="1">Option 1</option>
            <option val="2">Option 2</option>
            <option val="3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        is a <input type="text" name="isa">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Then copy that row as many times as needed:

```
​$(document).ready(function() {
    var $ul = $("ul"),
        $li = $ul.find("li.template"),
        i;

    for (i=2; i <= 10; i++)
        ​$li.clone().appendTo($ul).​find("span.qnum")​​​​​​.text(i);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/nnnnnn/kJd33/

Obviously I've elected to make each item an li element with an unordered list, but you could use an ordered list so that the items are numbered automatically, or if your real-world requirement has a number of columns then perhaps a table would be more appropriate.

Homework assignment for you: Google anything in my answer that you didn't understand, and/or look up the various jQuery methods I've used in the [jQuery API doco](http://api.jquery.com/).