# Consolidating HTML code <button>

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

http://js.do/code/lightsout5x5

Looking for a way to consolidate this HTML:

```
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s11" onclick="s11()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s12" onclick="s12()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s13" onclick="s13()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s14" onclick="s14()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s15" onclick="s15()">O</button><br>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s21" onclick="s21()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s22" onclick="s22()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s23" onclick="s23()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s24" onclick="s24()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s25" onclick="s25()">O</button><br>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s31" onclick="s31()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s32" onclick="s32()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s33" onclick="s33()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s34" onclick="s34()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s35" onclick="s35()">O</button><br>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s41" onclick="s41()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s42" onclick="s42()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s43" onclick="s43()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s44" onclick="s44()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s45" onclick="s45()">O</button><br>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s51" onclick="s51()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s52" onclick="s52()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s53" onclick="s53()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s54" onclick="s54()">O</button>
<button style="height:50px;width:50px" id="s55" onclick="s55()">O</button><br>
```

Makes a 5x5 squares for a Lights Out Program

Thinking of making it 9x9 but it would make the code 81 lines instead of 25.
Any way to consolidate the HTML?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code.

Comment: `<style>.a{height:50px;width:50px;}</style> ... <button style="a"...>` removes 529 characters.

Comment: Use some server-side (e.g. php) or client-side (javascript, possibly with jQuery or Angular) code seems like the obvious answer, but that's a very very broad question...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11919715/ This might help.

Comment: Thanks to SO help I was able to make a dynamic version that can change the puzzle size between 3x3 to10x10. Without having to hard code for every contingency. http://js.do/code/lightsoutpuzzles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start with a loop
then change your function to ONE function that passes the button - you can access its ID from it.

```js
function clicked(but) {
  var color = but.classList.contains("blue")?"blue":"red";
  but.classList.toggle("blue");
  but.classList.toggle("red");
  console.log("You clicked button "+but.id, "color:"+color);
}
var gridSize = 9, buttons=[], array_of_ids=[];
for (var i=1;i<=gridSize;i++) {
  for (var j=1;j<=gridSize;j++) {
    id = 's'+i+''+j;
    buttons.push('<button type="button" onclick="clicked(this)" id="'+id+'" class="but blue">&nbsp;</button>');
    array_of_ids.push(id);
    if (j==gridSize) buttons.push('<br/>');
  }  
}
document.querySelector("#container").innerHTML=buttons.join("")
```

```css
.but {height:50px;width:50px;}
.blue {background-color:blue}
.red {background-color:red}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: buttons.push('<button type="button" onclick="s'+i+''+j+''()'" id="s'+i+''+j+'" class="but">&nbsp;</button>') Trying this out so that each button has its own function. Doesn't want to work?

Comment: onclick="s'+i+''+j+'()"

Comment: Or onclick="'+id+'()"

Comment: Changed the function onclick="sc('+i+', '+j+')" so that I don't have to code for every button and insted pass in two numbers into a one single function.

Comment: That can be done cleaner by using id or data attributes and do onclick=sc(this)